# JS - print a String using window.print()

Tags: javascript, pdf

Can I use `window.print()` to print a `String`, I know it print the current page content. my final goal is to print to `pdf`, I had tried to use `jsPDF` lib, but it does not support `UTF-8`, so how can I print a `String` to pdf with this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to print just a string, best way is probably to create a temporary window, print it and then close it:

```
var win = window.open()
win.document.write('Some string')
win.print()
win.close()
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.